# Hive: timezone with T to date

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am accessing a hive database where the dates are stored in the following format and as `STRING(255)`

```
2014-12-22T00:00:00
```

In my SQL I used to the following in the past

```
where unix_timestamp(creation_date ,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss') >= unix_timestamp('01/01/2017 00:00:00','MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

Can someone tell me what format the unix_timestamp should be for this timestamp with a T.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below format:

```
 from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2014-12-22T00:00:00' , 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss'))
```